# How i can redirect several url with htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am currently developing a dashboard for my site but I have a problem with the configuration of my
.htaccess file. I will explain the problem:
I'm doing a redirect from

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)$ guild.php?guild_id=$1
```

`(.*)` = Server ID.
But I would like to have this too:

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)/features$ features.php?guild_id=$1
```

Except that it redirects me to the first file (guild.php and not features.php), I hope to have explained the problem well and that you could help me :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your attempted Rules, please try following htaccess rules. Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for uri which has feature in uri.
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]*)/features/?$ features.php?guild_id=$1 [NC,L]
##Existing rule from OP, fixed NC,L flags in rules too.
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)/?$ guild.php?guild_id=$1 [NC,L]
```